# funcion strstr(de la libreria string.h) hecha por mi

Tags: c, string, punteros

Hice un programa que simula ser la función `strstr`, de la libreria `string.h`. Se ingresan 2 cadenas por teclado y la función encuentra la segunda cadena en la primera devolviendo un puntero (si no la encuentra devuelve `NULL`) que apunte a la primera cadena (a donde se encuentra la segunda).

No se como realizar la función sin modificar la cadena original. Cuando la función retorna el "apuntador"(puntero tipo `char` que se retorna al `main`)y modifica automáticamente la cadena original, y no quiero eso.

Espero haber sido clara, desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define TAM 30
    char* mistrstr(const char*,const char*);
    int main()
    {
     char cadena[TAM];
     char cadena1[TAM];
     char *aparicion;
     printf("Ingrese la primer cadena:");
     gets(cadena);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Ingrese la segunda cadena:");
     gets(cadena1);
     fflush(stdin);
     aparicion=mistrstr(cadena,cadena1);
     printf("Primera aparicion (con mi funcion):%s\n",aparicion);
     return 0;
     }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    char* mistrstr(const char* cadena,const char* cadena1)
    {
      int i=-1;
      char *apuntador,*cad,*cad1;
      apuntador=cadena;
      cad=(char*)cadena;
      cad1=(char*)cadena1;
      while(*cad)
   {
       if(*cad1==*cad)
         i=0;
      else
         cad++;
      while(i>=0)
      {
         *(apuntador+i)=*cad;
         i++;
         cad++;
          if(*cad=='\0')
        {
            *(apuntador+i)='\0';
            return apuntador;
        }
    }
   }
     return NULL;
    }
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una cadena, por definición, termina con un caracter nulo.

La función `strstr` lo que hace es devolverte un puntero a la posición donde se encuentra la subcadena... pero **no modifica la cadena original**:

```
int main()
{
   const char cadena[] = "abcSubcadenadef";
   const char subcadena[] = "Subcadena";
   const char *ret = strstr(cadena,subcadena);

   printf("%s\n", ret);

   return 0;
}
```

Este ejemplo retornará:

```
Subcadenadef
```

Con esto en mente, lo único que hace la función es iterar sobre `cadena` y, en cada iteración, verifica si encuentra la `subcadena`:

```
const char* strstr(const char* cadena, const char* subcadena)
{
  for( ; *cadena; ++cadena )
  {
    const char* ptr1 = subcadena;
    for( const char* ptr2 = cadena; *ptr1==*ptr2 && *ptr1; ++ptr1, ++ptr2);

    if( *ptr1 == '\0' )
      return cadena;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es que tu función devuelva la subcadena en caso de encontrarla (finalizada con `'\0'`) no tienes muchas opciones:

- Devuelves `subcadena`. Tecnicamente es lo que quieres devolver y no necesitas modificar nada.
- Modificas `cadena`. Viable y sencillo pero no quieres hacer esto.
- Creas un array dinámico y copias ahí la cadena. Eso sí, tendrás que acordarte de liberar la memoria fuera del array... no es muy práctico.

A falta de que concretes un poco más qué es lo que esperas mi respuesta termina aquí. Mi opinión es que lo que pretendes es innecesario y artificioso (si haces una función para buscar una subcadena lo que te interesa es saber si se encuentra y dónde... recuperar la subcadena es absurdo porque es algo que ya tienes almacenado en la propia subcadena).

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias eferion! Solo hay algo que no me quedo claro: ¿Que es lo que hace el for de adentro? (El segundo for que se encuentra dentro de la funcion)no la entiendo por completo. Disculpa las molestias y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @micaela comprueba si la subcadena se encuentra a partir de esa posición. Se inicializan los dos punteros (uno para cada cadena) y se itera mientras los caracteres sean los mismos y no se haya llegado al final de la subcadena... y en cada iteración se incrementan ambos punteros. Al acabar el bucle (que no hace nada adicional, de ahí el punto y coma al final) se comprueba si el puntero de la subcadena apunta al caracter nulo y, de ser así, es que has encontrado la subcadena

Comment: Gracias! si!, utilice el debugger y observe eso!. Lo que hacia yo, en mi programa me modificaba la cadena original, y la profesora no quiere eso, me cuesta lograr ver esa diferencia, entre si modifico o no la cadena original.

Comment: @micaela Los punteros acceden a una memoria que puede estar compartida por varios... si modificas esa memoria los cambios serán visibles por todos los que apunten ahí. Si resuelves los ejercicios con lapiz y papel, dibujando los accesos y la memoria, verás que no es tan dificil

Comment: Por cierto, si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema márcala, por favor, como solución (salvo que prefieras esperar por si surgen nuevas respuestas). En cualquier caso no te olvides de marcar como solución la que mejor responda a tus dudas

Comment: Ya lo hice. Lo soluciona! Muchas gracias @eferion .